# How to get a panel's size in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, height, dimension

I tried to get with the `panel.getSize()` but it said `java.awt.Dimension[width=0,height=0]`

I tried `panel.getHeight()` but it said it is 0

Comment: If you provide some code to show how you're currently determining size, that would help a lot.

Comment: It sounds like it's 0x0. Do you have some reason to think it should be a different size?

Comment: It is a panel on panel in the center

`JPanel panel = new JPanel();`
 `panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(10, 20));`
 `panelMain.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);`
 `panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));`

Yes I know it is bigger than 0x0 because I see. I want to cut half this, and I want to set an other panel prefered height the half of this panel.

Comment: The size is zero until it is in a [displayable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Component.html#isDisplayable()) window.  You will need to add a HierarchyListener and read the size after the displayability flag changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Reason why your getting 0x0 as dimension is:

> You did declaration to find size earlier than JFrame and JPanel to render

I assume you Did This:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
System.out.println(panel.getSize()); // <-- This Line Triggers Earlier
panel.setVisible(true); // <-- Then This Line Renders the Panel, but late to recognize
```

To Fix this, Just Make Sure to Render All Objects First before getting the Info for size:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setVisible(true); // <-- Then This Line Renders the Panel first before recognizing
System.out.println(panel.getSize()); // <-- This Line Triggers Output Size
```

Bonus(in order to get info infinitely by using Listener of your choice, My Instance is MouseListener):

```
 import java.awt.Event.*;

        panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
          System.out.println("Size: " + panel.getSize());
            panel.repaint(); //This refreshes when user tries to resize
        }
    });
```

for sample:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.event.*;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hello world");
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setLocation(5, 5);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //JPanel Created
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    //You are getting 0x0 because you did first
    //System.out.println("Size: " + panel.getSize());
    panel.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    
    //Solution: Get Value by event of your choice
    //My instance is to use mouseListener mousePressed
    panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
      System.out.println("Size: " + panel.getSize());
        panel.repaint();
    }
});
  }
}
```

> Give a thumbs up if it helps. [Gladge](https://cdn.frankerfacez.com/emoticon/509860/4)